# Changing Firebase Database for a Recyclerview based on Button Click

Tags: android, database, firebase, android-recyclerview

In my application, there is a fragment. The fragment has 2 buttons on the top and in the rest of the portion there is a recyclerview. Say the buttons are B1 and B2. 
I want to make a system where on button B1's click the recyclerview will get data based on some database DB1 from Firebase and on button B2's click the recyclerview will get data based on some database DB2 from Firebase.
I.e., there are 2 databases and the data based on the databases are two be shown on a single recyclerview based on button click.

What I have done is there is a static global string named button_track that tracks which button is clicked. But it doesn't seem to work on the recyclerview. Recyclerview simply holds the DB1 which is the default database to be shown from the start. Only when I reload the page in my phone recyclerview takes database based on the string value.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
static String button_track ="b1";

//other code


//in onViewCreated

b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

button_track ="b1";

}

b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

button_track ="b2";

}


//in populateviewholder

if(button_track .equals("b1"))
{
//set db1 as the database for the Recyclerview

}

if(button_track .equals("b2"))
{
//set db2 as the database for the Recyclerview

}
```

I guess what I need is to set a listener that can track live when there is a change in buttonclick and hence it can change the database to be used. But currently I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: you may add 2 listeners to 2 references of DB1 and DB2 to get data when app starts (assume the data is stored in an array). After that, each time database change, don't forget to call adapter.notifyDataSetChange() to tell adapter update recyclerview.based on the data array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, try to get recycler view adapter with getAdapter() method in onClick(), and then just user notifyDataSetChanged() method.

For example:

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
```

If this isn't helpfully try to user Interface.

Comment: Yes. A little change and it actually helped. Thank you!!